# How to bind function to each object in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, eval

The question title may not be really clear or even inaccurate. However, this is what I want to do.

I want to have an array of objects. Each object will be a button. I want to bind predefined function to each button. A sample of the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/5wrm7/1/).

Currently, I'm using eval() but I know it's slow and and is considered a bad practice due to security reason. And it doesn't work either because the eval() function will execute right away and call the 2 functions that have been declared.

Can someone please suggest me what's the best approach to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the function in the array.

```
var myArray = [{id:"bt1", value:"+", func: func1 },
               {id:"bt2", value:"-", func: func2 }];
```

Then set the click event handler:

```
button.click(myArray[i].func);
```

Comment: that will make the array extremely huge and hard to read. What if the function spread several line long?

Comment: You can declare the function elsewhere and just put the name of the function in the array, as I have above.

Comment: Thanks a lot FishBasket. It works. BTW, do you know what's the difference btw writing obj.click(function(){}) and obj.bind('click', function(){})? Thanks

Comment: The first is shorthand for the second. Functionally, they are the same. I recommend reading through the jQuery API documentation: api.jquery.com. It's very informative.

Comment: @chepukha: `.bind()` does let you set data on the event object which is accessible via `event.data.someProperty`.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/tAZvz/2/

Basically what FishBasketGordo said about storing the functions, but also you have to use jQuery's `click` function to bind the events, not assign to `onclick`, since they are wrapped elements.

---

```
var func1 = function() { alert("Function 1 is called");}
var func2 = function() { alert("Function 2 is called");}

var myArray = [{id:"bt1", value:"+", func: func1},
               {id:"bt2", value:"-", func: func2}];


$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
       var button = $('<input type="button">');
       button.attr('id',myArray[i].id).attr('value',myArray[i].value);

       button.click(myArray[i].func);

       $('#test').append(button);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, Magnar. I accepted FishBasket because he answered earlier. But +1 for your jsFiddle. Thanks.

Comment: You're absolutely right about `click` versus assigning to `onclick`. I was correcting my answer as you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code quite a bit like this:

```
var func1 = function() { alert("Function 1 is called");}
var func2 = function() { alert("Function 2 is called");}

    // changed property name ----------v
var myArray = [{id:"bt1", value:"+", click: func1},
               {id:"bt2", value:"-", click: func2}];

$(function(){
    $.each( myArray, function(i,v) {
       $('<input>',$.extend({},v,{type:"button"})).appendTo('#test');
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yLPsK/

I used the [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to iterate your Array.

Then I used the [`jQuery.extend()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method to extend an empty object with the objects you created (changing `func` to `click`), as well as another one with the `type:"button"` info, and passed the result as the second argument to the [`jQuery()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) method.

If you add `type:"button"` to each object in your array, you can get rid of `$.extend`.

```
var func1 = function() { alert("Function 1 is called");}
var func2 = function() { alert("Function 2 is called");}

    // changed property name ----------v
var myArray = [{id:"bt1", value:"+", click: func1, type:"button"},
               {id:"bt2", value:"-", click: func2, type:"button"}];
    // added the "type" property -------------------^

$(function(){
    $.each( myArray, function(i,v) {
       $('<input>', v).appendTo('#test');
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yLPsK/1/

Comment: +1 . Thanks a lot Patrick. Your answer is very helpful.However, I didn't use each() because I need to control the number of buttons per row (that code was not included in my question), e.g. 3 buttons per row. And so each() does not allow me to do that, I guess?!

Comment: @chepukha: If you're saying that you need to break the loop after 3 buttons have been added, then just add `if( i == 2 ) return false;` to the `$.each` method. When `i == 2`, it will `return false`, and break the loop.

Comment: I couldn't post this extension as an answer to be clearer for reading because I don't have enough reputation. Sorry. I actually wanted to do something more beside calling the predefined functions when users click on the button.  
 Detail [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/5wrm7/2/)
 Because of closure, if I use myArray[i].func inside the anonymous function, 'i' will be equal to '2' and myArray[i].func becomes undefined. How would I fix this problem?

Comment: @chepukha: You need to create a new variable scope that captures the current value of `i`. Because a new variable scope is created in a function, you'd need to call a function, pass `i` to it, and have it return a function as the handler. Because the returned function was created in the same scope (the function) where `i` was passed, it will continue to have access to that `i` value. Using `$.each` is a nice way because you have a function execution for each iteration that references an `i` value. Any function created inside that `$.each` will continue to have access to `i`.

Comment: ...here's another example using `$.each()` http://jsfiddle.net/yLPsK/3/ The click handlers created in the `$.each()` function reference `myArray[i].func`. Because `i` is a parameter to that specific function invocation, the handler created will continue to reference that specific `i`.

Comment: Another +2. Thank you so much, Patrick. You really saved my day.